# Prefilled p:inputText component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am not able to display a `p:dialog` with prefilled values for a `p:inputText` component:

```
<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="editPersonDlg" header="Edit Person" width="350">
    <h:form id="editPersonForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="editFirstName" value="First Name:" />
            <p:inputText id="editFirstName" value="#{personBean.selectedPerson.firstName}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Save" type="Button" actionListener="#{personBean.edit}" 
                                 oncomplete="editPersonDlg.hide()"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="Button" oncomplete="editPersonDlg.hide()"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

When debugging I see that `personBean#selectedPerson` is effectively returning a not-null Person, with not-null names. `Person#getFirstName` is effectively returning a not-null name. However FirstName and LastName don't appear in the inputText boxes of the Dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be beacause you don't update the dialog before you open it.
For example: 
You initialize the personBean.selectedPerson by selecting it in p:dataTable and then you want to edit it by clicking on p:commandButton which opens the "edit" dialog. You have to update this dialog so the component can fetch actual data. Try something like this for the button which opens the dialog:

```
<p:commandButton value="Edit" oncolmplete="editPersonDlg.show()" update=":formInWhichIsDialog:dialogID" />
```

Let me know if it worked, problem can be somewhere else but this is the most common thing.
Hope it helped !